# What's the meaning of exception code "EXC_I386_GPFLT"?

Tags: c++, c, exc-bad-access

What's the meaning of exception code `EXC_I386_GPFLT`?

Does its meaning vary according to the situation?

In that case, I'm referring to exception type `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with exception code `EXC_I386_GPFLT`

The program is developed in Xcode 5.0.1, dealing with `cblas_zgemm()` of the BLAS library.(Well, I guess it doesn't matter...)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 131):

EXC_I386_GPFLT is surely referring to "General Protection fault", which is the x86's way to tell you that "you did something that you are not allowed to do". It typically DOESN'T mean that you access out of memory bounds, but it could be that your code is going out of bounds and causing bad code/data to be used in a way that makes for a protection violation of some sort.

Unfortunately it can be hard to figure out exactly what the problem is without more context, there are 27 different causes listed in my AMD64 Programmer's Manual, Vol 2 from 2005 - by all accounts, it is likely that 8 years later would have added a few more.

If it is a 64-bit system, a plausible scenario is that your code is using a "non-canonical pointer" - meaning that a 64-bit address is formed in such a way that the upper 16 bits of the address aren't all copies of the top of the lower 48 bits (in other words, the top 16 bits of an address should all be 0 or all 1, based on the bit just below 16 bits). This rule is in place to guarantee that the architecture can "safely expand the number of valid bits in the address range". This would indicate that the code is either overwriting some pointer data with other stuff, or going out of bounds when reading some pointer value.

Another likely causes is unaligned access with an SSE register - in other word, reading a 16-byte SSE register from an address that isn't 16-byte aligned.

There are, as I said, many other possible reasons, but most of those involve things that "normal" code wouldn't be doing in a 32- or 64-bit OS (such as loading segment registers with invalid selector index or writing to MSR's (model specific registers)).

Answer (score 28):

You can often get information from the header files.  For example:

```
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
$ find usr -name \*.h -exec fgrep -l EXC_I386_GPFLT {} \;
usr/include/mach/i386/exception.h
^C
$ more usr/include/mach/i386/exception.h
....
#define EXC_I386_GPFLT          13      /* general protection fault     */
```

OK, so it's a general protection fault (as its name suggests anyway).  Googling "i386 general protection fault" yields many hits, but this [looks](http://www.on-time.com/rtos-32-docs/rttarget-32/programming-manual/x86-cpu/protected-mode/) interesting:

> Memory protection is also implemented using the segment descriptors.
>   First, the processor checks whether a value loaded in a segment
>   register references a valid descriptor. Then it checks that every
>   linear address calculated actually lies within the segment. Also, the
>   type of access (read, write, or execute) is checked against the
>   information in the segment descriptor. Whenever one of these checks
>   fails, exception (interrupt) 13 (hex 0D) is raised. This exception is
>   called a General Protection Fault (GPF).

That `13` matches what we saw in the header files, so it looks like the same thing.  However from the application programmer's point-of-view, it just means we're referencing memory we shouldn't be, and it's doesn't really matter how it's implemented on the hardware.

Comment: Modern OS's don't use segments for memory protection in general, however. It is all done with the MMU, and would lead to a PF, vector 14 (usually displayed as "Segmentation fault").

Answer (score 28):

To debug and find the source:
Enable Zombies for the app (Product\Scheme) and Launch Instruments, Select Zombies. 
Run your app in Xcode
Then go to Instruments start recording.
Go back to your App and try generating the error. 
Instruments should detect bad call (to zombie) if there is one.

Hope it helps!

Comment: [how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)

Answer (score 22):

I wondered why this appeared during my unit tests.

I have added a method declaration to a protocol which included `throws`; but the potentially throwing method wasn't even used in that particular test. Enabling Zombies in test sounded like too much trouble.

Turns out a ⌘K clean did the trick. I'm always flabberghasted when that solves actual problems.

Comment: This fixed it for me in Swift, too. Thanks!

Comment: Clean build folder for me is: Shift+⌘+K

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar exception at Swift 4.2. I spent around half an hour trying to find a bug in my code, but the issue has gone after closing Xcode and removing derived data folder. Here is the shortcut:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the error was thrown in Xcode when running an app on the iOS simulator. While I cannot answer the specific question "what the error means", I can say what helped me, maybe it also helps others.

The solution for me was to `Erase All Content and Settings` in the simulator and to `Clean Build Folder...` in Xcode.

Comment: Worked for me - cleaning build folder was enough.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when leaving a view (pop back to the previous view).

the reason was having

```
addSubview(view)
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Change `safeAreaLayoutGuide` to `self` solve the issue.

Meaning aligns the view with the superview's leading, trailing, top, bottom instead of to safe area)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't use the correct placeholder in the `format` parameter of  `String.localizedStringWithFormat`:

```
let format = "I have an %s."
let string = "exception"
String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, string)
```

Changing `%s` to `%@` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because Xcode didn't appear to like me using the same variable name in two different classes (that conform to the same protocol, if that matters, although the variable name has nothing related in any protocol). I simply renamed my new variable.

I had to step into the setters where it was crashing in order to see it, while debugging. This answer applies to iOS

Answer (score 0):

If the error is thrown inside a closure that defines `self` as `unowned`, you may be limited in what you can access and will get this error code in certain situations. Especially while debugging. If this is the case for you try changing `[unowned self]` to `[weak self]`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while doing this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:<#(nonnull id), ...#>, nil]; //with 17 objects and keys
```

It went away when I reverted to:

```
NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[aDictionary setObject:object1 forKey:@"Key1"]; //17 times
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this error code in rotation crashes on Xcode 12.0 Beta 6, only on the iOS 14 simulator. It doesn't crash on my real device running iOS 13 though! So if you're running beta stuff and seeing rotation crashes in the simulator, maybe you just need to run on a real device with a non-beta iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

I could get this error working with `UnsafeMutablePointer`

```
let ptr = rawptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: A.self) //<-- wrong A.self Change it to B.Self
ptr.pointee = B()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `EXC_I386_GPFLT` was caused by missing return value in the property getter. Like this:

```
- (CppStructure)cppStructure
{
    CppStructure data;
    data.a = self.alpha;
    data.b = self.beta;

    return data; // this line was missing
}
```

Xcode 12.2

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the stupid Xcode Playground. The playground has been unstable for me since it came out years ago, Apple is so messed up.

Deleting derived data etc. didn't help, the only way to make my code not throw was to run it in an app project

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error on Swift/iOS.
In my case it was because I was trying to start `(NS)Operation` by directly using its `start()` function. But instead what I needed to do is to pass it to `OperationQueue`. Something like this `var queue = OperationQueue(); queue.addOperation(myOperation)`

Answer (score 0):

Old question. Not much Objective-C stuff being asked so will throw my penny in. Might help someone.

Had the typical EXC_BAD_ACCESS and was struggling with what on earth was causing it.

After some deliberation, I discovered it was caused by my code referring to a variable inside a block that was defined outside the block and not using the __block pre-fix. And the variable referred to was being passed to a method call inside the block and referred from and define as an auto-releasing parameter.

Hard to explain in words. So, an example = code to delete customers in an array I was enumerating using a block. "error" is passed in. I then pass this to a method called in the block. The value of error param is changed in the method call. I then try to refer to this outside of the block. And that's when I get the bad access. Probs a little unrelated to the OP's question but goggling the problem put me on this page and someone else might find this useful.

```
- (BOOL)deleteCustomer:(CHCustomer *)customer
                 error:(NSError *__autoreleasing*)error {

    __block BOOL success = YES;
    NSMutableArray *customerOrders = [self ordersForCustomer:customer 
                                                       error:error];
    if ([customerOrders count] > 0) {
        [customerOrders enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj,
                                                     NSUInteger idx,
                                                     BOOL *stop) {
        
            CHOrderHeader *orderHeader = (CHOrderHeader *)obj;
            if (![self deleteOrderForOohSeqNo:[orderHeader oohSeqNo]
                    preserveExistingPhotoKeys:NO
                                        error:error]) {
            
                *stop = YES;
                success = NO;
            }
        }]; // enumerateObjectsUsingBlock
    }

    // EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurred on line below:    
    NSLog(@"Is this an NSError? %@", [*error class]);

    return success;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it issue related to storyboard there is option of ViewController build for set iOS 9.0 and later previously set for iOS 10.0 and later. Actually i want to downgrade the ver from 10 to iOS 9.3.