# C General Protection Fault trying to access object in array

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, macos, exc-bad-access

In my program, I store objective-c objects in a c array, like this

```
va_start(list, o);
retval->objs = malloc(SIZE * count);
retval->objs[0] = (__bridge void *)o;
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
{
    id o = va_arg(list, id);
    retval->objs[i] = (__bridge void *)o;
}
va_end(list);
```

(`count` is a number containing how many objects will be added; that value is always correct)

`objs` is a `void **` and is part of `retval`, which is a pointer to a struct. As of now, `SIZE` is defined as 100. Increasing and decreasing that had no effect.

As you can see, I bridge `o` to a `void *`, as I have to. `objs`, when all the objects are added, contains 3 objective-c objects. When I try to access a value like this

```
void *obj = CLArrayObjectAtIndex(_arr, ind);
return (__bridge id)obj;
```

this is the `CLArrayObjectAtIndex()` function

```
void *CLArrayObjectAtIndex(CLArrayType *arr, int ind)
{
    void *o = arr->objs[ind];
    if (o)
        return o;
    else
        perror("Attempt to access NULL object or index out of bounds."), abort();
}
```

if the index (`ind`) is 0, it works. If the index is 1, the program crashes when it returns in `main`. If the index is 2, the program crashes as soon as I try to access it. If the index is 1, the value returned above is correct, but when the program crashes on return it is `nil`.

If the index is 1, the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` code is 1; if the index is 2, the code is `EXC_I386_GPFLT`, a general protection fault. I already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651788/whats-the-meaning-of-exception-code-exc-i386-gpflt) for an explanation of this exception, although I couldn't find anything helpful. So, does anybody see why this error may be occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you store obj-c objects in C array don't just bridge cast them since that way arc doesn't know they are still used and releases them. __bridge_retain them so they stay around later, when you free the array __bridge_transfer them to give them back to ARC

also don't define size as 100..  sizeof(id) should work. You only need to store pointers