# UIAlertView EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use a `UIAlertView` to show an alert in iPhone6. where delegate is called nil. When I pressed the ok button of alert then it's automatically crashed and there is no error message. It only shows `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`.

Given bellow the code:

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"This First ALert" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
```

Comment: If you don't pass any `otherButtonTitles` then only one `nil` is sufficient at the end of method call :)

Comment: Please read this question answer
link:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651788/whats-the-meaning-of-exception-code-exc-i386-gpflt

Answer (score 0):

Please check it.

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"This First  ALert" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You just added extra nil into `otherButtonTitles`

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"This First ALert" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Hop this helps.