# How can I set a delegate for a CALayer?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift3, calayer

I'm trying to set a `CALayer`'s delegate so that I can use `draw(_:in:)`. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayerdelegate/2097262-draw) describes how to do it. But as soon as I set the delegate, there's a runtime error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Here's code that generates an error. Replace `ViewController.swift` in the Single View Application template in Xcode 8.2.1:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myLayer = CALayer()
        myLayer.delegate = LayerDelegate()
        view.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)
    }
}

class LayerDelegate: NSObject, CALayerDelegate {
}
```

Comment: `CALayer`'s `delegate` property is `weak`, so setting a new object like that to it is going to cause it to deallocate immediately. Not sure if that's the source of your exception, though...

Comment: according to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19652248/1179863 EXC_I386_GPFLT is surely referring to "General Protection fault", which is the x86's way to tell you that "you did something that you are not allowed to do". It typically DOESN'T mean that you access out of memory bounds, but it could be that your code is going out of bounds and causing bad code/data to be used in a way that makes for an protection violation of some sort.

Comment: Did you try `class ViewController: UIViewController { let layerDelegate = LayerDelegate()  override func viewDidLoad() { ... myLayer.delegate = layerDelegate }}`?

Comment: The documentation example has the delegate saved into a strong reference within a property. Maybe this is a prerequisite, and the `weak` reference is actually an `unowned` one, thus you get a crash because the delegate gets deallocated.

Comment: @Yannick That worked. Thanks! I made it an answer but if you create your own, I'll accept yours instead.

Comment: @Cristik That explanation makes sense, and adding a strong reference fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Robert Adding a strong reference does indeed stop the exception, so that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is removed from memory because there is no strong reference to it. As the other @Robert pointed out, `CALayer`'s `delegate` is `weak` and once you leave the scope, which is the `viewDidLoad()` function, the object is removed from memory.

You need to make sure that it is not deallocated. You can add a property to your class. This will live as long as the class lives.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let layerDelegate = LayerDelegate()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myLayer = CALayer()
        myLayer.delegate = layerDelegate
        view.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)
    }
}
```